# which database is best h2 or sqlite for java?

Tags: java, sqlite, hsqldb

i am developing a small project in java called slambook.i need some suggestion that which database should be use ***h2 or sqlite***.my project does not deal with client and server. .
**which database gives better performance**?

Comment: Have you tried googling "h2 vs sqlite"? https://www.google.com/search?q=h2+vs+sqlite&oq=h2+vs+&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3.3265j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: yes but i did not get any information about performance.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer HSQLDB.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm just curious. Do you have any particular reason to prefer HSQLDB over H2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And again another interesting question closed too early.

Comment: I haven't found the proper benchmarks but these are interesting:
http://lightjavadatabase.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/choosing-light-weight-java-database.html
http://www.jpab.org/Hibernate/HSQLDB/embedded/DataNucleus/DB4O/embedded.html
http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html

It seems that has similar performance than HSQLDB, and both are better than sqlite.
You could also be interested in db4o  or  snappydb.